# error in Test Class System.DmlException: NVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, error, dml

Getting this error in Test Class

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, only portal users can be associated
>   to a contact: []

Here is the specific method

```
@future
 public static void createUser(Id ContactId, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String profileId, boolean IsPortalEnabled) {
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Partner Community User Custom'];
        User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email=email, 
            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname=lastname, languagelocalekey='en_US', 
            localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id , contactId=contactId, 
            timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', //IsPortalEnabled = false,
            username=email);

    u.setOptions(dmo);
    insert u;

        IsPortalEnabled = true;
        system.setPassword(u.Id, '');

    update u;
}
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
static testMethod void createCustomerPortalUserTest() {
    customerPortalCls cpTest = new customerPortalCls();
    List<SelectOption> profileOptions = cpTest.getCustomerPortalProfiles();
    cpTest.a= new Account(name='TestMethod Account Name');
    cpTest.c = new Contact(firstName='TestFirstName', lastName='TestLastName', email='test@testorg.com');
    cpTest.u = new User(username='testusername@abc.com');
    Profile[] profiles = [Select p.name, p.id From Profile p where p.UserLicense.Name like '%Partner Community User Custom%'];
    //cpTest.selectedProfileId = profiles[0].id;

    Test.startTest();
        cpTest.checkForNewUser();
        PageReference testPageRef= cpTest.createPortaluser();

    Test.stopTest();
    PageReference testPageRef2 = cpTest.reset();
    cpTest.checkForNewUser();

}

static testMethod void createCustomerPortalUserTestNullUsernameError() {
    Boolean errorFound = false;
    customerPortalCls cpTest = new customerPortalCls();
    cpTest.a= new Account(name='TestMethod Account Name');
    cpTest.c = new Contact(firstName='TestFirstName', lastName='TestLastName', email='test@testorg.com');
    cpTest.u = new User();
    Profile[] profiles = [Select p.name, p.id From Profile p where p.UserLicense.Name like '%Partner Community User Custom%'];
    //cpTest.selectedProfileId = profiles[0].id;

    Test.startTest();

        PageReference testPageRef= cpTest.createPortaluser();

    Test.stopTest();
    ApexPages.Message[] mssgs = ApexPages.getMessages();
    for(ApexPages.Message m : mssgs){
       if(m.getDetail()=='Username is required: Please a username for the new user')
          errorFound=true;
    }
    System.assert(errorFound==false);
}

 static testMethod void createCustomerPortalUserRequiredFieldErrors() {
    Boolean errorFound = false;
    customerPortalCls cpTest = new customerPortalCls();
    cpTest.a= new Account();
    cpTest.c = new Contact(firstName='TestFirstName', lastName='TestLastName', email='test@testorg.com');
    cpTest.u = new User();
    Profile[] profiles = [Select p.name, p.id From Profile p where p.UserLicense.Name like '%Partner Community%'];
    //cpTest.selectedProfileId = profiles[0].id;

    Test.startTest();
        PageReference testPageRef= cpTest.createPortaluser();
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! I'm kinda stumped at this point

Also, not sure why some of the code isn't displaying in the right format. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Is it your intent to create a Portal User or a Standard User? If you wish to create a Portal user, you need to query for the Profile that uses a portal user license. Depending on your org (old orgs could still be using Customer Portal vs. new orgs can only enable Communities, etc.), the name of the Profile is different. (and obviously you could have cloned one of the standard ones and have your own customized portal Profile)

Alternatively, you can find any old portal Profile by specifying the UserType in your Profile query

```
SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE UserType = 'CspLitePortal' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yeah so I had that originally in the query, however in this sandbox the customer doesn't have any community licenses & doesn't wish to pay for more, so I was trying to find a way around that

Comment: How old is the sandbox? If it was created within the past ~6 months or so, the license types should propagate from Production -> Sandbox via a button. Prior to Summer '14, you had to do a refresh. See http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sandbox_copy_licenses.htm

Comment: Gotcha, Ill try this! It's older than 6 months old, and they do not want to do a refresh. It's weird I know, but they are very particular about their sandbox. I'm gonna test it tomorrow and see if it works. This issue might not be closed after I try this so an admin might want to keep it open until tomorrow

Comment: So now i'm getting another on this, I've included the updated code and the test class. System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: